# Printing tab to a csv file

Tags: java, printwriter

I want to print a tab character to a csv file to be able to open it accurately with excell using a java `PrintWriter`, but it seems like it doesn't print this character to a file.
I am printing as follows:

```
PrintWriter pw = new Printwriter(new FileWriter(file));
pw.print(myvariable+"\t")
```

Comment: Are you closing the **PrintWriter** after writing?

Comment: yes I am. This is just a snippet of the code

Comment: How are you determining that it didn't work? Is anything written on the same line after the tab?

Comment: When I open it the file with the excel the result that I am expecting is having data in different cells. But all of them are in one cell. Meaning for string "data1\tdata2\t" , data1 and data2 should be in different cells, but i end up having them in 1 cell. ..There is nothing written in the same line after the actual data

Comment: I just checked, if I change file extension from .csv to .xls it is opened appropriately in excell (data on different cells)... But I still do not understand the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Default behavior:**

> I just checked, if I change file extension from .csv to .xls it is
>   opened appropriately in excell (data on different cells)... But I
>   still do not understand the issue

`.csv` = `comma separated value` so if you want to use a `.csv` simply use the character `,` instead of a `\t`.

---

**Tell Excel the separator for your current file**

Add: `sep=\t` in the first line of your `.csv` this will tell excel to use this as separator. (Source: https://superuser.com/a/420025/438867)

---

### Code example can be found here in this [github repo](https://github.com/DominikAngerer/StackoverflowJavaAnswers/tree/master/src/main/java/com/dominikangerer/q29718239)

**Change the separator in all .csv text files**

According to [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba)

In Microsoft Windows, click the **Start** button, and then click **Control Panel**.

Open the **Regional and Language Options** dialog box.

Do one of the following:

In Windows Vista, click the **Formats** tab, and then click **Customize this format**.

In Windows XP, click the **Regional Options*** tab, and then click **Customize**.

Type a new separator in the **List separator** box.

Click **OK** twice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems weird that you have a problem there, I'd recommend that you use a library for this rather than rolling your own so you don't run into issues with regard to escaping etc.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

By just creating a FileWriter you're not specifying to Java what character encoding format you want the file written in so it will be the default format for the machine the code is running on (so you'll get different behaviour on Macs vs Linux vs Windows) - this may not be what you want.